# Why can't I save a photo to some other directory in iPhoto?

Tags: iphoto

Is there some good reason why there is no "Save As" menu item in iPhoto?

If I want to share a photo to a different Facebook account, I need access to the photo!

iPhoto as a program seems determined to keep me within its confines. Right now I am only able to email the photo to myself to gain access to the file.

Is there another way?

iPhoto version 9.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Export option to export one or several pictures.

Select the pictures you want to export, then go to *File -> Export* or press *Shift + Command + E*.

Answer (score 1):

Not to sure where the stupidity lies. iPhoto has an export function in the file menu which offers many different ways of getting one or more photos out of the library.